# Location of Windows COA sticker on Dell PowerEdge R710

Tags: dell-poweredge, licensing

I'm asking somebody at a remote location to find the Windows Product key / Certificate of Authenticity for a Dell PowerEdge R710 that shipped with Windows Server 2008.  Where should I ask them to look?

I'm guessing it's a sticker on the server rather than on a CD sleeve, but is there a usual location for the sticker?

Comment: If you just want the cd key, and have remote access to the server, it'd likely be easier to just use a key retrieval app like ProduKey.

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek Thanks! I hadn't thought of that. the only issue is that it's DataCenter edition and I understand the sticker has a separate 'Virtual Key' that I should use for for Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on top of the server at the front on the left hand side.

If your server is mounted in a rack with something else above it, it will probably need to be slid out on the rails by 4-5 inches, in order to view the label.

Answer (score 2):

Dell tends to leave room for that on the top cover.

Answer (score 2):

Dell R710's have a pull out tab on the front of the server that will show the servers serial number and other dell info. If this is an OEM copy of windows it might be on the tab. That said I have never seen a 710 that has the windows key sticker on it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a rack server it's most commonly on the top cover, or the back. If it's a tower it's usually on the back or the side. In any case it should be pretty easy to find unless the server is burried in the DC.